# Wiley Authoring Template Problem

Tags: templates, books

I have downloaded the [Wiley Book Style template](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/book-authors/prepare-your-manuscript/wiley-latex-template.html), moved the complete file to my latex folder, then compiled with pdflatex but the output pdf has several problems, there is a diagonal shifting in every page.

The correct pdf (form the site )
[image: The correct pdf (form the site )]

The pdf after compiling using the Wiley Template.

[image: The pdf after compiling using the Wiley Template]

I  cannot find the mistake.

The log file

( I cannot upload it sorry, I have not used the forum for 3 years)

---

The main.tex

```
%% Run LaTeX on this file several times to get Table of Contents,
%% cross-references, and citations.

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{Wiley-AuthoringTemplate}
\usepackage[sectionbib,authoryear]{natbib}% for name-date citation comment the below line
%\usepackage[sectionbib,numbers]{natbib}% for numbered citation comment the above line

%%********************************************************************%%
%%       How many levels of section head would you like numbered?     %%
%% 0= no section numbers, 1= section, 2= subsection, 3= subsubsection %%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%%********************************************************************%%
%%**********************************************************************%%
%%     How many levels of section head would you like to appear in the  %%
%%              Table of Contents?          %%
%% 0= chapter, 1= section, 2= subsection, 3= subsubsection titles.  %%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
%%**********************************************************************%%

%\includeonly{ch01}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Title Pages
%% Wiley will provide title and copyright page, but you can make
%% your own titlepages if you'd like anyway
%% Setting up title pages, type in the appropriate names here:

\booktitle{Efficient Multirate \\ Teletraffic Loss Models \\
Beyond Erlang}

\subtitle{Efficient Multirate Loss Models}

\AuAff{Ioannis D. Moscholios\\ University of Peleponnese}

\AuAff{Michael D. Logothetis\\ University of Patras}

%% \\ will start a new line.
%% You may add \affil{} for affiliation, ie,
%\authors{Robert M. Groves\\
%\affil{Universitat de les Illes Balears}
%Floyd J. Fowler, Jr.\\
%\affil{University of New Mexico}
%}

%% Print Half Title and Title Page:
\halftitlepage
\titlepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Copyright Page

\begin{copyrightpage}{year}
Title, etc
\end{copyrightpage}

% Note, you must use \ to start indented lines, ie,
% 
% \begin{copyrightpage}{2004}
% Survey Methodology / Robert M. Groves . . . [et al.].
% \       p. cm.---(Wiley series in survey methodology)
% \    ``Wiley-Interscience."
% \    Includes bibliographical references and index.
% \    ISBN 0-471-48348-6 (pbk.)
% \    1. Surveys---Methodology.  2. Social 
% \  sciences---Research---Statistical methods.  I. Groves, Robert M.  II. %
% Series.\\

% HA31.2.S873 2004
% 001.4'33---dc22                                             2004044064
% \end{copyrightpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Only Dedication (optional) 

\dedication{To my parents}

\tableofcontents

%\listoffigures %optional
%\listoftables  %optional

%% or Contributor Page for edited books
%% before \tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Contributors Page for Edited Book
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% If your book has chapters written by different authors,
% you'll need a Contributors page.

% Use \begin{contributors}...\end{contributors} and
% then enter each author with the \name{} command, followed
% by the affiliation information.

 \begin{contributors}
 \name{Masayki Abe,} Fujitsu Laboratories Ltd., Fujitsu Limited, Atsugi, Japan

 \name{L. A. Akers,} Center for Solid State Electronics Research, Arizona State University, Tempe, Arizona

 \name{G. H. Bernstein,} Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, University of Notre Dame, Notre Dame, South Bend, Indiana; formerly of
 Center for Solid State Electronics Research, Arizona
 State University, Tempe, Arizona 
 \end{contributors}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Optional Foreword:

\begin{foreword}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{foreword}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Optional Preface:

\begin{preface}
\lipsum[1-1]
\prefaceauthor{}
\where{place\\
 date}
\end{preface}

% ie,
% \begin{preface}
% This is an example preface.
% \prefaceauthor{R. K. Watts}
% \where{Durham, North Carolina\\
% September, 2004}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Optional Acknowledgments:

\acknowledgments
\lipsum[1-2]
\authorinitials{I. R. S.}  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Glossary Type of Environment:

% \begin{glossary}
% \term{<term>}{<description>}
% \end{glossary}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{acronyms}
\acro{ASTA}{Arrivals See Time Averages}

\end{acronyms}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\begin{introduction}

The word 
\end{introduction}

\mainmatter
\include{ch01}
\include{ch02} 
\backmatter
\include{app01}

\latexprintindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example because we cannot find the mistake too... may be you have used `\\\` in the title but this is just a guess

Comment: Here is the log file, I did not add anything to the main.tex, I have just try to complile the file.

Comment: The problem exist in every page

Comment: The same problem occurs when I use overleaf

Comment: Just add a little part of your code and not log files... A part starting from `\documrntclass`, ending in `\end{document}` and gives some undesired result like in your photos... If you don't nobody can help you

Comment: Also you can share a "read" link from overleaf... but this is not recomended here.. No future users can be helped this way

Comment: Also the code exists in the link, thnx.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not even compile the original example and this means that it is probably outdated. Not an answer but believe me.. the best advice in such cases is not to use the template... The sentance about "sing the Wiley LaTeX template allows authors to focus on the content rather than the appearance of their submission." can be said (and it is said) for the whole LaTeX project too and so means nothing

Comment: What do you mean outdated? this is the newest version (2017).

Comment: Did you tried to compile their own main.tex? You will find it gives error... You can contact with them if you confirm the error and they have to fix and update their template

Comment: Yes, the original main.tex does not give me any error.

Comment: I can not compile because I have an error: `\ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}` about `hyperref` package

Answer (score 1):

If you add the package geometry without parameters (\usepackage{geometry}) the bug disappeared !!!!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{Wiley-AuthoringTemplate}
\usepackage[sectionbib,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
......
\end{document}
```

!!!